# How to test Facebook apps with many users/friends?

Tags: facebook

I'm working on developing a Facebook application that accesses the user's friends list.
Since some can have thousands of friends, what's the best method to simulate this?
I want to performance test before letting it out in the wild.
Does Facebook have any sandbox account where one can create dummy accounts?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Facebook have recently implemented a feature allowing you to add up to 50 test users, it's probably not enough users to reliably test though:

http://developers.facebook.com/docs/test_users/

Why not ask a couple of users with lots of friends to beta test for you?

Comment: Note that the limit is now 500 test users, and see this question of mine: http://facebook.stackoverflow.com/questions/10364579/facebook-test-users-api-500-user-limit-a-way-to-test-my-app-with-more-than-500